# Bootstrap carousel not working(php+wordpress+bootstrap)

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a bit php with Bootstrap carousel

```
    <?php if( magic_get_attachment() ): 
        $attachments = magic_get_attachment(7);
        //var_dump($attachments);
    ?>

        <div id="post-gallery-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">          

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                <?php 
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach($attachments as $attachment): 
                    $active = ($i == 0 ? ' active' : '');
                ?>

                    <div class="item<?php echo $active; ?> background-image standard-featured" style="background-image: url(<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ); ?>);"></div>

                <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>


            </div><!-- .carousel-inner -->

        </div><!-- .carousel -->

    <?php endif; ?>
```

When I inspect in Chrome, I can see all images have been stored

But it seems the carousel is not sliding. something wrong with my code?
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

bootstrap carousel cannot get along with jQuery version higher than 3.